# Can someone show this strange equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

The solution in the book says
$$ 
\frac{4}{5^{2/3}+5^{1/3}+5}
$$
and the solution I calculated is
$$
\frac{-25^{1/3}+5}{5}
$$

Apparently **these describe the same number**.

However, I tried to show the equality and came nowhere.

Any idea on how to prove the equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A difference of cubes can be factored as $$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(1+x+x^2).$$ Plugging in $x=5^{1/3}$, we have $$5-1=(5^{1/3}-1)(1+5^{1/3}+5^{2/3})=(1-5^{-1/3})(5^{1/3}+5^{2/3}+5).$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Oh awesome, I didnt know of this trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Nurator Consider accepting the answer if it answered your question

Comment: @AlexD I tried to but you answered too fast. I had to wait a few minutes and then fogort about it.